# Strange IP's on my firewall log

Tags: network, firewalls, denial-of-service, router

Check the screenshot of my router firewall log below, I can see traffic originating from strange IP addresses to my public address.

What are these?

I've just setup this router few hours ago, am I being hacked or part of DoS attack?

[image: firewall log]

Comment: so what is the **port no.** of these **ip's** and the status `Established` or `listening` or what ??

Comment: The internet is FULL of botnets scanning every IP, I have discovered 74,000 so far.  In 2 days 40,000 probes reached my ip.  Don't have any open in bound port and move on with your life.

Answer (score 1):

These are probably the attempts of some P2P software, like Bittorrent, Skype ...
See also [Why are packets constantly being sent to international ISPs?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/97553/why-are-packets-constantly-being-sent-to-international-isps)

Comment: Thanks is this bad or good? should i be worry about this? i'm not running any P2P stuff at the moment

Comment: @user1419170: no need to worry about these. Apart from that todays hacks usually cannot be detected by simple packet filter firewalls on a router since these attacks are at the application level, i.e. drive-by-downloads etc. And if this would be DoS attack you would probably notice it because your internet would get really slow. And you would probably get lots of packets per second and not one every few second.